# How to replace characters at specific position in several words using REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query similar to this:

```
SELECT YEAR_CODE FROM YEAR_CODES
```

and it returns several records: typically 1 but sometimes 2 or 3. The returned records look like this: `2018FOO`, `2019BAR`

I need to get the matching previous year of the returned codes. For instance:

- 201**8**FOO becomes 201**7**FOO
- 201**9**BAR becomes 201**8**BAR

Looking for something similar to:

```
REGEX_REPLACE(SELECT YEAR_CODE FROM YEAR_CODES, 4th character, 4th character minus 1)
```

Comment: what if you have `2010FOO` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan `2010FOO` should become `2009FOO`

Comment: then `4th character minus 1` should be stated as `number composed of first four characters`...

Comment: What about 2020ARG?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica `2020ARG` should become `2019ARG`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `regexp_replace()`, using `substr()` string operator with `concat()` function (or concatenation operators `||`) is enough :

```
with year_codes(year_code) as
(
 select '2018FOO' from dual union all
 select '2019BAR' from dual 
)
select concat(substr(year_code,1,4) - 1,substr(year_code,-3)) as year_code
  from year_codes;

YEAR_CODE
---------
2017FOO
2018BAR
```

`to_number()` conversion is redundant, since Oracle implicitly considers a string as a number which is completely composed of digits for an arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use string operations:

```
with c as (
      <your query here>
     )
select
from year_code yc
where to_number(substr(yc.code, 1, 4)) = to_number(substr(c.code)) - 1 and
      substr(yc.code, 5) = substr(c.code, 5)
```